# In cygwin I could not modify files in my home directory

Tags: cygwin

In my `cygwin` terminal, I could not modify files in my home directory

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/user123

$ cd $HOME

$ pwd
/home/user123

$ ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 user123 None 0 Jan  2 16:46 .

$ touch foo
touch: cannot touch `foo': Permission denied

$ whoami
user123
```

However, if I `Run as administrator` when I started the `cygwin` terminal, I could modify the file

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/user123

$ cd $HOME

$ pwd
/home/user123

$ touch foo

$ ls -ld foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 user123 None 0 Jan  2 17:00 foo

$ whoami
user123
```

How can I fix this problem?  Thanks!

**Update**

I checked the folder properties as recorded by Windows, it shows that the check box for "Read-Only" has been checked. (See a screenshot below.)  I tried unchecking it but that did not help.  Also I noticed two things:

1. The check-box label says "Read-Only (Only applies to files in folder).  Does that mean folders are not marked as "Read-Only" not matter what the status of the check box is?  Apparently my current problem is that the *home folder* is marked as read-only (except for Administrator).  How do I change that?
2. When I tried to change the "Read-Only" status (unchecked the box and the `Apply`), I got a lot of pop-up that said

   An error occurred apply attributes to the file  Access is denied.

The relevant filepaths are all the files that start with a dot (.) (UNIX hidden files).  In my operation, I chose to option of `Ignore` for these pop-ups

[image]

**Update 2**

The following is the screenshot for the security tab.  Note that I the `Add` button is grayed out (even though I was doing this with `Run as administrator`).  Also, when I entered the tab, there is a pop-up with this message:

```
The permissions on user123 are incorrectly ordered, 
which may cause some entries to be ineffective.
```

[image]

One more question: how do I know how the two users with long numerical IDs (S-1-5-21-...) are mapped to the symbolic usernames?

Comment: Can you write to the folder outside of Cygwin? Check Windows permissions for your user on that folder.

Comment: @simlev -- I could write outside of that folder.  As for Windows permissions, please see my updated question -- basically I saw that the folder has "Read-Only" (partially checked), but I don't know to to change the state for that.

Comment: I was asking whether you can write (e.g. create files) *inside that folder* from *outside of Cygwin*. I would ignore the `Read-only` attribute. Permissions are found in the `Security` tab, then click on `Advanced`.

Comment: @simlev -- Indeed I could not write to the folder outside of `cygwin` (e.g. using `Windows Explorer`).  Also, I added "Update 2" to my question.  Please take a look. How do I change the settings for security?  (The `Add` button is grayed out)  How do I map the users' symbolic name to their numerical IDs?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I now know how to interpret those SIDs (S-1-5-21-...), thanks to this explanation: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html But I still cannot change the settings (even when I `Run as administrator`).  I also tried "elevating permission" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298823.aspx) still could not get the UI to allow me to change the permission

Comment: Login to Windows as the administrator. If the permissions are not too messed up you should be able to give "Full control" to `user123` on its home folder.